# reset a field(s) in a HTML form not working

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a huge project due soon and I cannot for the life of me figure out why the form fields do not reset when I click my button. Does anyone have any helpful guidance? I added the checkbox later in the code, using bootstrap, but used HTML form to make the form, because I wanted to make it differently than the Form bootstrap has.

```
<form className='employee-details' data-transport-order="form">
                        <div className='form-group'>
                            <label htmlFor='UserFName'>* FIRST NAME</label>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="employee_first_name" required value={user.employee_first_name} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserLName'>* LAST NAME</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_last_name" required value={user.employee_last_name} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='Username'>* USERNAME</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_username" required value={user.employee_username} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserPassword'>PASSWORD</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="UserPassword" readOnly></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserContactNo'>* CONTACT #</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_contact_no" required value={user.employee_contact_no} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserAddress'> STREET ADDRESS</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_street_address" value={user.employee_street_address} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserCity'> CITY</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_city" value={user.employee_city} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserState'>STATE</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_state" value={user.employee_state} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserZip'>ZIP CODE</label>
                            <input className="form-control" id="employee_zip_code" value={user.employee_zip_code} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                            <label htmlFor='UserEmail'>EMAIL</label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="example@gmail/yahoo.com" pattern=".+@(gmail|yahoo)\.com" className="form-control" id="employee_email" value={user.employee_email} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.currentTarget.id, e.currentTarget.value)}></input>
                        </div>
                        <Form>
                            {
                                <div key={`default-checkbox`} className="mb-3" >
                                    <Form.Check
                                        type={'checkbox'}
                                        onChange={() => {
                                            if (isAdmin === "false" && isDriver === "true"){ //If the checkbox is already checked, user is Admin. 
                                                setDriver("false");
                                                setAdmin("true");
                                            }
                                            else { //If the checkbox is already checked, user is Driver.
                                                setDriver("true");
                                                setAdmin("false");
                                            }}
                                        } 
                                        id={`default-checkbox`}
                                        label={`Is Driver`}  
                                    />
                                </div>
                            }
                        </Form>
                   <button type="reset" className={"btn btn-primary"} onclick="document.getElementById('employee_email').value =''">RESET</button>
                   <button type="deleteUser" className={"btn btn-primary"}>DELETE USER</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="reset" className={"btn btn-primary"} onClick={() => changeVal('employee_email', '')}>RESET</button>
```

The error occurs because the onclick attribute on the "RESET" button must be written with lowercase letters, instead of onclick it must be onClick. In JSX, event syntax must be camelCase and not kebab-case.

See if correcting it solves the problem, if not, I'll set up a page to test your code

Comment: It unfortunately didn't work on my end. :( I really appreciate the help though!!

Comment: What you want is to clear all the form fields when you click on the reset button?